# Can't edit DjangoCMS Plugin in foreign language -> returns 404

Tags: django, plugins, content-management-system, http-status-code-404

I'm on an old installation of DjangoCMS, namely DjangoCMS 2.4.3 with Django 1.4.3.

This page exists in German and English. When I try to edit or add a plugin I'm getting a 404 error. This only happens in Frontendediting. I can edit all these plugins without any problems in Django backend.
Fun fact: This only happens in English – German pages are fine.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be? Or any hints, how to debug that phenomenon?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself: Since I've update the cms from an older version, also the static files had to be updated. I forgot to manage.py collectstatic on my server.